# Grok debugging - Match first only regex not working as intended

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, logstash-grok, grok

So I have the following log message:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] SystemPropertiesConfigurer$ExportingPropertyOverrideConfigurer loadProperties    > Loading properties file from class path resource [SystemConfiguration.overrides]
```

I'm trying to match the first thread ( [localhost-startStop-1]  ) with the following pattern:

```
EVENT_THREAD (\[.+?\])
```

This works when I pass it into regex101.com but doesn't work when I represent it as

```
%{(\[.+?\]):EVENT_THREAD} on grokdebugger for reasons unknown to me...
```

Can someone help me understand this?

Thanks,

Comment: You must define it as a custom named pattern. Or, just use a named capture group: `(?<EVENT_THREAD>\[.+?\])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Grok help](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html):

> Sometimes logstash doesn’t have a pattern you need. For this, you have a few options.
>
> First, you can use the Oniguruma syntax for named capture which will let you match a piece of text and save it as a field:

```
(?<field_name>the pattern here)
```

So, use `(?<EVENT_THREAD>\[.+?\])`.

> Alternately, you can create a custom patterns file.
>
> Create a directory called patterns with a file in it called extra (the file name doesn’t matter, but name it meaningfully for yourself)
> In that file, write the pattern you need as the pattern name, a space, then the regexp for that pattern.

```
# contents of ./patterns/postfix:
EVENT_THREAD (?:\[.+?\])
```

> Then use the `patterns_dir` setting in this plugin to tell logstash where your custom patterns

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
    match => { "message" => "%{EVENT_THREAD:evt_thread}" }
  }
}
```